# Missing Menu Items in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I had recently create a menu contains various headers and sub-headers. Then change default template in blend 2017 (customize it).
After that Main-heads are visible but sub-heads are missing.
You can see the code below.

Before doing this, it works fine.

My XAML code :

```
  <MenuItem Header="Options" Foreground="White">
            <MenuItem Header="Volume" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                <MenuItem Header="Full" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Half" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Mute" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Increase By" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Increase To" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator Style="{DynamicResource SeparatorStyle1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Playlist" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <Separator Style="{DynamicResource SeparatorStyle1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Repeat" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Repeat All" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Shuffle" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <Separator Style="{DynamicResource SeparatorStyle1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play by Duratiuon" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                <MenuItem Header="Are less than 5 minutes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Are less than 10 minutes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Are less than 15 minutes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Are less than 30 minutes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Are less than 1 hour" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Play Videos only" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play Audios only" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play Non-Stop with list" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play Non-Stop without list" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play even indexes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Play odd indexes" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"/>
        </MenuItem>
```

It looks like this :
[Screen-Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMR1e.png)

Selection time image [Selection type screen-shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8oLM.png)

My Menu Template (Created by blend auto, I just change the background and selection colors)  :

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="0" Background="Black"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" Background="Black"  ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden"     VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="RoyalBlue"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF6027CB"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF6027CB"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Below is my Separator Template (green color separator in image you can see, but this is not have any impact. The sub-headers become invisible after applying upper Menu-Template but you can also inspect this one as well )

My Separator Template :

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Separator" Color="Green"/>
    <Style x:Key="SeparatorStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green"  BorderThickness="1" Background="Green" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

What's wrong with it, any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Abhi

Comment: What happens when you click volume?

Comment: Nothing Happens, the side arrow is also not visible.

Comment: Remove the Template bindings for each and then check.

Comment: It works but then default design restores.

Comment: see the new selection-time screenshot  below the old-one. Working of main-headers is fine but the sub-headers are missing as you can see.

Comment: So it is most likely the template. Please post it.

Comment: I had post my both templates but the second one is not the reason it is just for clearing doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `ControlTemplate` is the issue here. There is more to creating a custom `ControlTemplate` for a `MenuItem` than copying the default template using Blend.

You will need to define a `TopLevelHeader` template as well as a `TopLevelItem` and a `SubmenuItem` template as well. Please refer to the official documentation for more information about this.

**Menu and MenuItem ControlTemplate Example:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates

If you want to copy the default templates you could use a decompiler such as [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and decompile the `PresentationFramework.Aero2` assembly.